# when i launch an activity from list activity the application stops

Tags: android

I am currently learning to build apps from thenewboston but when I launch an activity from the listactivity the application stops.here's my code:

[this is listactivity code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tV8e.png)

[this is my manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocL5a.png)

Comment: Please share error logs .

Comment: You are not declaring the other class in manifest.

Comment: See your intent you are moving from Menu activity to another which is com.example.android."Your class name...."which are example1,example2.. and so on. This example1, example 2 etc are not declare in manifest.

Comment: Also make sure class name(example1 , example2 ...etc) ends with .class extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should define all the activities in your manifest file that's why you are getting an error.Define all your class in your manifest which your array contains.

You should create all activities like you have example1 ,example2...

Comment: I tried this but now the app is not stopping but the activity is also not starting

Answer (score 0):

In your `Menu` activity you have `Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.android." + ourClass)`

**But**  in your manifest it seems your package name is `com.gupta34.rishabh`

so change this `Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.android." + ourClass)` in your `onListItemClick` method to `Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.gupta34.rishabh." + ourClass)` and it should work as long as you click on `MainActivity`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried this also but main activity is not starting

Comment: if you could post Logs, I will be able to help better.

Comment: sorry but I am new to android studio so could you please tell how to see logs

Comment: Logs are just system messages that you can find in Logcat console, look up for Android logging or logcat tutorials, I'm sure you'll find something.

Comment: Before I go on and tell you what could be wrong I'm gonna have to ask for your your ListActivity code as well, I'm kind of embarrassed right now but it would be better if I know what I'm working with you know.. I do have an idea what may be wrong with your code but i need to be sure. So just share your ListActivity if you may.

Comment: I have added my listactivity code please see it and then please tell me where I am wrong